# Windows Server VPN access

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, server, vpn

I have configured SSTP VPN on windows server 2019 with ADDS,RRAS and CA services installed in it. I'm able to get connect using when VPN is assigned in static ip address but when i choose i am not able to get connect through SSTP Vpn.

Problem: I need to configure VPN is such a way that any user can able to get connected through VPN from any network.
please help me out where I'm lacking to configure VPN connection.

I had tried to configure DHCP Server Relay agent but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the similar issue. I was able to configure VPN in VPS server by referring to [this article](https://www.accuwebhosting.com/blog/install-vpn-rras-remote-routing-access/).

I can connect my all devices the VPN and can access internet without any issue. Please see if those steps works for you.